# Document ID changes when I move a document to another library?

Tags: workflow, document-id

What happens with the document ID if a workflow moves the document to another library? 
According to this [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-and-configure-unique-Document-IDs-ea7fee86-bd6f-4cc8-9365-8086e794c984?CorrelationId=26cfa827-2152-4d61-bdae-1ac53f9e0b3a&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) the only way to keep the DocId is moving the document through the **Site Content and Structure administrative page** but what happens if it's the workflow who moves the document?

Comment: why don't you just test it?

Comment: Yes, I can test it but it'll save me a bunch of time if somebody's done this before. This is the purpose of communities like this, right?